# I created pages in notification, the code shows no error but in wear, not showing me any pages

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I created pages in notification, the code shows no error but in wear, not showing me any pages....Here's the code :

```
    int notificationId = 001;
    // Build intent for notification content
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
    viewIntent.putExtra("Helllo", "Hello Wear !");
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 
            .setContentTitle("My App") 
            .setContentText("Hello Wear !")
            .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

    // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();


            // Create builder for the main notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Page 1")
                .setContentText("Short message")
                .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

        // Create a big text style for the second page
        BigTextStyle secondPageStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        secondPageStyle.setBigContentTitle("Page 2")
                       .bigText("A lot of text...");

        // Create second page notification
        Notification secondPageNotification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setStyle(secondPageStyle)
                .build();

        // Create main notification and add the second page
        Notification twoPageNotification =
                new WearableNotifications.Builder(notificationBuilder)
                .addPage(secondPageNotification)
                .build();
```

The code shows now error and runs fine, but is showing one page only instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the one-page-notification you get show "My App" / "Hello Wear !"?

This would be logical, because you are building this notification (var `notificationBuilder`) and actually have it displayed (`notificationManager.notify()`).

For the two-page notification, you create the first and second page - but when merging the first and the second page into `twoPageNotification`, you are using `notificationBuilder` instead of `notificationCompatBuilder` for your first page.

Additionally, that built, two-page notification `twoPageNotification` is never passed to the `notify()` function. So adding a `notificationManager.notify(notificationId,twoPageNotification)` should display those two pages.

Comment: It's giving error when i added : notificationManager.notify(notificationId,twoPageNotification), says there is some error in twoPageNotification.